# I get a "command not found" error, though the script file is shown by "ls"

Tags: shell-script, php, path, command-not-found

I want to run `yii` console commands in shell. 
I run `protected/yiic` in the console, yet it fails, yielding `-bash: yiic: command not found`

What's the problem?
See the shell commands and responses I have:

```
ls -l
...
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213   94 Aug 21 09:26 test 
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213   75 Aug  4 21:05 yiic 
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213  395 Aug  4 21:05 yiic.bat
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213  178 Aug  4 21:05 yiic.php
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ test
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ test
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ yiic
-bash: yiic: command not found
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ yiic.php
-bash: yiic.php: command not found
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$
```

the `yiic` content:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/yiic.php');
```

the `yiic.php` content:

```php
defined('STDIN') or define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/yii.php');

if(isset($config))
{
  $app=Yii::createConsoleApplication($config);
  $app->commandRunner->addCommands(YII_PATH.'/cli/commands');
}
else
  $app=Yii::createConsoleApplication(array('basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).'/cli'));

$env=@getenv('YII_CONSOLE_COMMANDS');
if(!empty($env))
  $app->commandRunner->addCommands($env);

$app->run();
```

## Update

I've changes the permissions as suggested, yet now when i run 
`./yiic` the result is **: No such file or directory**
With `./test` it works fine:

```
-rwxr-----  1 srv50213 srv50213   94 Aug 21 11:33 test 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 srv50213 srv50213   75 Aug  4 21:05 yiic 
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213  178 Aug  4 21:05 yiic.php
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ test
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ ./test
test OK
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ ./yiic
: No such file or directory
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ echo $PATH  
  /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/web/users/srv50213/bin
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$
```

What's wrong?

## Update 2

Actually yiic.php contains:

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yiic.php'; 
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/main.php';

require_once($yiic);
```

where `/../../framework/yiic.php` is the path to the framework's yiic.php file exposed in main part of question. There is the yii.php file in the framework folder too.

```
[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ cd ..
[srv50213@cl10-m doc]$ cd .. 
[srv50213@cl10-m htdocs]$ cd framework
[srv50213@cl10-m framework]$ ls -l
total 432
drwxr-s---  2 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:37 base
drwxr-s---  3 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:37 caching
drwxr-s---  5 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:37 cli
drwxr-s---  2 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:37 collections
drwxr-s---  2 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:37 console
drwxr-s---  4 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:38 db
drwxr-s---  9 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:38 gii
drwxr-s---  4 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:41 i18n
drwxr-s---  2 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:41 logging

drwxr-s--- 11 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:45 web
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213  37100 Jul 16 23:37 YiiBase.php
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213    358 Jul 16 23:37 yiic
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213    577 Jul 16 23:37 yiic.bat
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213    834 Aug 21 13:05 yiic.php
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213 304900 Jul 16 23:37 yiilite.php
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213    638 Jul 16 23:37 yii.php
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213    175 Jul 16 23:37 yii-powered.png
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213    694 Jul 16 23:37 yiit.php
drwxr-s---  4 srv50213 srv50213   4096 Jul 16 23:45 zii
[srv50213@cl10-m framework]$
```

Should i change mode (chmode) for  yii.php and yiic.php in framework folder too?

## Update 3

as suggested i ran `[srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ php yiic.php` and it issued php debug info:

```
    exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CConsoleApplication.defaultController" is not defined.' in /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CComponent.php:173
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CModule.php(515): CComponent->__set('defaultControll...', 'site')
    #1 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CApplication.php(161): CModule->configure(Array)
    #2 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/YiiBase.php(125): CApplication->__construct('/home/srv50213/...')
    #3 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/YiiBase.php(113): YiiBase::createApplication('CConsoleApplica...', '/home/srv50213/...')
    #4 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/yiic.php(23): YiiBase::createConsoleApplication('/home/srv50213/...')
    #5 /home/srv50213/htdocs/doc/protected/yiic.php(7): require_once('/home/srv50213/...')
```

## DONE

Thank you to everyone. One problem was in there (as stated in debug info) `/home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/yiic.php(23)` with `$config` -  `$app=Yii::createConsoleApplication($config);`.
So I've changed the $config var in */home/srv50213/htdocs/doc/protected/yiic.php(5)* from `$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/main.php';` to 
`$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php';` and it has worked!!!

**Should i still run `php yiic.php` instead of `./yiic` for example in cron command?**

Comment: You might want to add `<?php` to the beginning of `yiic.php`, but that's unlikely to cause the problem with `: No such file or directory`. That's more likely a space somewhere, such as the one at the beginning of your `$PATH`.

Comment: Try the command `php yiic.php` from the folder that contains `yiic.php`, `yiic`, and `test`.

Comment: Do you have **two files with the same name `yiic`**, in directories `protected` and in `framework`? Same for `yiic.php`?

Comment: @MattBianco, this command `php yiic.php` issued in real debug info -  [srv50213@cl10-m protected]$ php yiic.php
exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CConsoleApplication.defaultController" is not defined.' in /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CComponent.php:173
Stack trace:
#0 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CModule.php(515): CComponent->__set('defaultControll...', 'site')
#1 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CApplication.php(161): CModule->configure(Array)
#2 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/YiiBase.php(125):

Comment: @IgorSavinkin - please edit your Q with this stuff. Keep adding update sections as you go along, rather than dump this in a comment.

Comment: @Volker Siegel, it's true (the two files yiic.php in 2 diff dirs). Designed by yii framework though.

Comment: i've edited my q. with _update 3_

Comment: From comparing to the code, the filename left out in last error line (`require_once('/home/srv50213/...')`) refers to the file `framework/yiic.php`.

Comment: see the `DONE` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

The first is that you do not have the execute permission:

Add the permission for you with:

```
$ chmod u+x yiic
```

It gives `u`, the user - you - the `x`, execute permission.

The second, separate issue is about how you call the program, and how it is found.
Now you have the execute permission, but

```
$ yiic
```

will probably still give you a `command not found` error.

That is because a command you run is searched for in the directories listed in the variable `$PATH` - which does not include the current directory normally (and should not include it for security reasons).

But you can give a file name of the command to run, by including a directory path for the command file. The simplest variant of this is just using the current directory:

```
$ ./yiic
```

That should finally work!

If it works without the `./` in front too, then you have the current directory, `.`, in your `$PATH` - take a look at it:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

(Oh, and then, there is the famous issue of using the file name `test` for testing something... that's a pretty bad trap I would say - you are not the first person getting bitten by this one... )

Comment: thank you, it really the thing you stated. But when i run `./yiic` the responce is `: No such file or directory`. What's wrong?

Comment: For `./yiic` to work, you need to be in the same directrory. Otherwise, you need to use either a different relative path like `foo/yiic` if you are in your home directory and the file is in `/home/igor/foo/yiic`, or an absolute path, like `/home/igor/foo/yiic`.

Comment: but php is trully installed on server.  [srv50213@cl10-m protected]`$ command -v php` 
`/usr/bin/php` how to resolve it?

Comment: The `#!/usr/bin/env php` should find the php program in $PATH, and it's in $PATH. But if you want to test, you could try `#!/usr/bin/php` as first line instead. But the error message `: No such file or directory` is strange. I do not know php actually, so I can only guess, maybe it's the `yiic.php` that is not found inside `yiic`. Hmm... but you also `require` a file `yii.php` - are you sure it exists? I can not tell from the name, as I do not know what "yiic" or "yii" mean.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin I think `yii.php` may be missing indeed - the line `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/yii.php');` reads it from the current directory, but the `ls` does not show it. But it shows `...` I just noticed - so check whether is is there.

Comment: i've checked the files and summed up in Update 2. Seems should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

You should to remove Win (CRLF) in first line;

If you open file in mcedit you will see:

## !/usr/bin/env php^M

change it to

## !/usr/bin/env php

Comment: That's a good one !

Answer (score 1):

The permissions on the file `yiic` are not set so that it can be executed.

```
-rw-r-----  1 srv50213 srv50213   75 Aug  4 21:05 yiic
```

You can set it like so:

```
$ chmod u+x yiic
```

It should then look like this:

```
-rwxr-----  1 srv50213 srv50213   75 Aug  4 21:05 yiic
```

#### Why did test work?

You may think that you were running `test` but in actuality you were running one of the nother commands called `test` which are located here:

```
$ type -a test
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
test is /bin/test
```

This is assuming that you're using Bash as your shell, but the cause is likely to be the same, that you're running another version of `test`.

To make sure you're running a command that's present in the current directory, it's always a good idea to prefix it with a dot slash, i.e.: `./test`. This forces the shell to run `test` from the current location, rather than searching your `$PATH` looking for one to run.

Comment: @sim, thanks for the **Why did test work?** section.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin - you're welcome. Thanks for the Q.

Comment: I have `#!/usr/bin/env php` at the beginning of yiic file (taken from yii framework). So what does it mean? Should i uncomment it for running php.exe?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin that's making that script a PHP script. That line is calling the PHP interpreter which will then parse the remainder of that file, executing its contents. I would seem there is more to that `yiic` file, than what's being shown here to us.

Comment: seems i have no path to php.exe in $PATH:

Comment: @IgorSavinkin - you must if the `command -v php` returned a path to `php`.

Comment: seems there is no path to php.exe in $PATH -    $ echo $PATH
/usr/bin/env:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/web/users/srv50213/bin. How could i locate it and add path to php.exe into $PATH ?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin - `$PATH` points a list of directories. The entries are separated by `:`. The directory, `/usr/bin` is where the `php` executable likely lives.

Comment: It does, then why when i run `./yiic` i still have **: No such file or directory** ?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin - the No such file... is a result of something within the script, not the script itself. Based on the output it looks like a colon, `:`.

Comment: @slm I think the `:` is part of the error message, and the message is showing an empty file name. (`:` is also a shell builtin command - that would not be found in path, but I do not think it's involved)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - you're likely right. Try `php yiic`.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin - try this pls: `php yiic`.